# How to use Android vector drawables as background for an activity?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I am unable to set a vector drawable xml as background in an Android activity.

I tried to set it as background by setting `android:background="@drawable/test_background"`

- to the Coordinator layout root of my activity.
- to the Coordinator layout child Constraint layout
- to an `ImageView` child of the `ConstraintLayout` via `app:srcCompat"= @drawable/test_background"`

None of the above approaches worked. I can see only a black screen in the design preview, and my application crashes with a Fatal exception:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Here is an outline of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/test_background"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay">

       <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
           <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
           </android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>

       </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The test_background drawable is an xml vector asset created from a png image, converted to an svg in Inkscape, and exported into an xml asset via an Inkscape plugin. The png image contains a kind of pattern, and I never really transformed anything on it to a path. So it looks like this:

```
<vector xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ns0:name="svg869" 
    ns0:width="1382.2272dp" 
    ns0:height="2073.3408dp" 
    ns0:viewportWidth="666.666666667" 
    ns0:viewportHeight="1000.0"/>
```

However, I did confirm that the plugin is exporting the xml successfully because I can set the xml background successfully as an icon (for example as a logo/icon).

My problem is that I cannot set the vector as background.

Are there any attributes that I need to set within the drawable in order to use it as background for an activity? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your SVG into an Android Vector Asset. You can easily do this with Android Studio.
Right click your project > New > Vector Asset. Then Select "Local File" and enter the file location/path

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, just tried it. Getting an error: **Cannot generate preview**. It does not allow me to proceed to the next step.

Comment: This works provided the SVG file is smaller than 2MB.

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://duongkk.wordpress.com/2017/08/30/using-vector-drawable-as-background-of-view-in-android-lower-20/) you must create a new layer drawable to hold vector drawable. This implementation is for Pre-Lollipop devices. Devices with Lollipop and above don't need this. I've tested it and it works i.e irrespective of the type of rootview you have.

Comment: This does not work. I tried the example with my own vector and it crashes on Android 4.1. When I remove the background field, everything is ok.